# What does `empty` mean in a JS array?

Tags: javascript, syntax, google-chrome-devtools

Can anyone help me understand what an `empty` means in a JS array?

I just noticed an array in chrome devtools with an empty value.  I created the one below, and by putting two commas together I can produce an `empty` (see below).  Granted, I'm relatively new to JS, but since `empty` isn't a JS primitive I would have expected either:

a) a `null` or `undefine3d` value for `a[3]`

b) `a.length` to be 4

What does `empty` mean?

[image: devtools screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Array literals can include *elisions*, e.g.

```
[0,1,,3];
```

The two commas together mean "there is no element at index 2". Many stringified versions will show *undefined* at index 2, however that is misleading as there is no element at all at that position.

E.g.

```js
let arr = [0,1,,3];

arr.forEach((v, i) => console.log(`index ${i} has value ${v}`)); 

console.log('stringified: ' + arr);
console.log('SO console:', arr);
console.log('JSON: ' + JSON.stringify(arr));
```

An alternative is to show "empty", which (IMHO) isn't really suitable either, it should be shown as in the literal (i.e. as for "stringified").

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain their vote? Neither of the duplicates covers elisions, or "empty".